# Flyway doesn't recognize schemas and default-schema property in application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, flyway

Spring Boot 2.4.5.
FlyWay 6.5.5.

I decided to make an experiment on my local machine.
I dropped my app database.
All my migrations include `my` as schema for creating tables, sequences etc.
For instance:

```
create table if not exists my
(
    name varchar not null
        constraint category_pk primary key,
    status varchar
);
```

I run `./gradlew api:flyWayMigrate`.

`my` schema has been created along with tables from migrations under it.
But there is no `flyway_schema_history` tables under `my` schema.

`Public` schema has been created as well, but it contains only one table `flyway_schema_history`.

Wrapping up, `my` schema contains all tables, but doesn’t contain `flyway_schema_history` table.  `public` schema contains `flyway_schema_history table`, but doesn’t contain other tables.

When app is being started, FlyWay complains that you have tables in `my` schema but you don’t have `flyway_schema_history` table for them, use baseline property.

Baseline property was not what I expected to have. I need the single schema - `my` with `flyway_schema_history` in it.

So I have added these lines into `application.properties` files.

```
spring.flyway.schemas=my
spring.flyway.default-schema=my
```

But it didn’t help.
Only by adding `schemas = ['my']` in `build.gradle` FlyWay section, I have achieved the result, when there are all needed tables under `my`
schema along with `flyway_schema_history` table.

```
flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres'
    user = 'postgres'
    password = 'password'
    locations = ['classpath:sql']
    schemas = ['my']
}
```

So my question is why `spring.flyway.schemas` and `spring.flyway.default-schema` properties in `application.properties` don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess its because you are using jpa hibernate which also does migrations

Comment: Hey @WARUTS. Could you please provide more details on this matter?

Comment: have you set  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=true in the application proprties?

Comment: I have this one `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`

Comment: make it none or false, since they carry out the same function with flyway